# Connecting via sockets between two machines on home networks?

Tags: c, winapi, sockets, winsock

I am newbie at sockets, and my question is this:

Let's say that I have a home computer and my friend has 
a home computer too. 
(I am connecting to net by gprs/edge modem; my friend 
connects by wire - I'm not sure if this matters).

I can check my ip for example on `whatismyip.com` page; he
can do it also for his.

If I wrote some simple socket (WinSock) code and 
put those ip's in such code, will it be sufficient to make some network communications between our machines, 
and will it work, or not?

Where to put such ip's in WinSock example code?

*Edit:* some explanations

I am using c/winapi 
I' ve compiled and tested some example locally on my own machine 
and it seem to work, but I am not sure If it will work on two
remote computers if I will provide two IP's (getted from 
whatismyip.com page).

It will work for sure or maybe not? Need I only provide
those IP's in some socket address fields or do I need to do some more?

*edit2:*

I need to make some simple winapi game between two home
computers (connection over internet via winsock)
I can turn off firewalls, wouldnt it work?
How to make it work?

Comment: This code will not work. Your respective machines are behind firewalls. The IP's you see on whatismyip.com [www.whatismyip.com] is not that your machine has. Run `ipconfig` in a DOS shell to see your IP. As @Nikolai N Fetissov mentioned below, reading up on NAT and Port Forwarding concepts will help you understand better.

Comment: It will NOT work if the receiving machine is behind a router, unless the router is configured for port forwaridng.  If both PCs are NOT behind routers, then it WILL work, provided the ISP of the receiving PC is not blocking the port on their end (most ISPs require you to pay extra to run your own servers).

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which most home routers do. Then add a [port-forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) rule to your router/modem firewall.

Comment: So WHEN it will work, how can i recognize such situations, There is no way of establishing such connection (it is made for simple games ) without router options manipulation? I want to make some simple game or chat between two home computers over internet with winsock - how to do it?

Comment: It is the matter of firewall/routers settings only and then it will work ?

Comment: If you are behind NAT, you need to either connect out to some known globally routable address (this is when your side acts as a *client*), or configure you router to allow connections in to your computer (your side is the *server* accepting connections). All this applies to both TCP and UDP, just with UDP you don't have explicit notion of connection, just one side starts listening for a packet first.

Comment: sorry but sadly I can not fully understand it. My question too put it simple is - how to test my winsock (tcp client/server procedures) simple games with minimal effort

Comment: Test on two computers on a local network, i.e. connected to the same routers.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choices. One is to set up static port forwarding -- i.e., configure your router so port X goes to internal IP address a.b.c.d. This generally requires that you set up your computer using a static IP address though.

Most people would generally prefer to avoid that -- which is possible, but not necessarily trivial. Some of the available tools/protocols are [STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389), [TURN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766), [ICE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245), and [UPnP](http://www.upnp.org/). Though you can use UPnP directly, you may find it a bit easier to deal with via a library like [libupnp](http://pupnp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I have a telephonic-card modem (gprs/edge) modem conection, and i have no router, one of my friends probably has home-router (he is computer administrator so possibly could set his router ok), the second one probably has gprs/edge connection too - so could anyone tell me how exactly should I do with minimal effort to test my winsock client server procedures? Call to my gprs/edge friend asked him about ip and send him client or server code, put his IP in it and fire it?

Comment: @user982377: About the only difference that may make is that you may not have a NAT router involved (but then again, you might).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decide on which protocol you want to be using.
TCP or UDP?
If you want TCP/IP communications, you need one computer to be the server (listening), and one computer to be the client.

Are you programming this in C++?
Here's an example of the server side [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1891/Beginning-Winsock-Programming-Simple-TCP-server):

Comment: I added some explanations, as to udp or tcp I would prefer easiest one, TCP probably